# Ruby Error: koala no such file to load LoadError

Tags: ruby, koala, koala-gem

I have installed Ruby (not Rails) on a machine and am trying to run some code based off the koala framework for Facebook.
When I run

```
    gem list
```

koala is mentioned but when I run the file, I get this error. Rubygems is already installed, I'm not sure what else to do. Any ideas?

Edit:

```
    require 'koala'
    require 'json'

    @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new("CAACEdEose0cBANb7YuygrBflSkBrpdalb4e70T5lJgdLPYEh0Uxy5JLPVdukKSiwZAK8g27DnwscSUWNaC0s53ogq6h562LETjYO4sB5lZAMAy8tC0SM9UzqXkk7GKYpaLrkQlgj1oLTdOJhBfq5KJtFxZBkOkpz8HaVPLYp66OnuGkaGOogVseR1tUNXVxToKl6ZCmwHL0i5RHNvMnd")




    url = File.open("urls.txt","r")
    url.each_line do |line|
        id = /[\d]+/.match(line)
        begin
            temp = @graph.get_object(id)
            list = File.open("working.txt", "a")
            list.write(id)
            list.write("\n")
            puts "Worked for #{id}."
        rescue
            puts "Didn't work for #{id}."
        end      
    end
```

Comment: Compare the output of `gem contents koala` (where koala files are) and `ruby -e "puts $:"` (where Ruby searches for requires). You might have a version mismatch, using gem from one ruby version but executing with another.

Comment: @Amadan: What am I looking for?   
        gem contents koala returns a list of koala 2.0.0 files in /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems.     
Second command points to /usr/lib/ruby/1.8, /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8, /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby, etc. among others.

Comment: @Amadan: Additional edit, I installed ruby 1.9.3 and now the output for the first has 1.9.1, second has 1.8 still.  Still get the same error on the first line(which contains require 'koala').
ruby -v returns 1.8.7

Comment: After installing Ruby 1.9, you now have a mismatch, and it won't work unless you use new gem and new ruby. Before... no idea, everything seems to have been okay.